# getAnnotation(Class<T>) always returns null when I'm using EasyMock/PowerMock to mock java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: junit, easymock

The tested method has the following code:

```
SuppressWarnings suppressWarnings = method.getAnnotation(SuppressWarnings.class);
```

In my test method.I mocked java.lang.reflect.Method:

```
Method method= PowerMock.createMock(Method.class);  
SuppressWarnings sw = EasyMock.createMock(SuppressWarnings.class);  
EasyMock.expect(method.getAnnotation(SuppressWarnings.class)).andReturn(sw);
```

In the tested method,
method.getAnnotation(SuppressWarnings.class); always returns null.

I don't know why.Could anyone help me?

```
//code:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Anonymous {

}

public class AnnotationClass {
    public Anonymous fun(Method m){
        Anonymous anonymous = m.getAnnotation(Anonymous.class);
        return anonymous;
    }
}

// test class:
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Method.class)
public class AnnotationClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        AnnotationClass testClass = new AnnotationClass();
        final Method mockMethod = PowerMock.createMock(Method.class);
        final Anonymous mockAnot = EasyMock.createMock(Anonymous.class);

        EasyMock.expect(mockMethod.getAnnotation(Anonymous.class)).andReturn(mockAnot);
        PowerMock.replay(mockMethod);

        final Anonymous act = testClass.fun(mockMethod);
        Assert.assertEquals(mockAnot, act);

        PowerMock.verify(mockMethod);
    }
}

error:
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<EasyMock for interface  
com.unittest.easymock.start.Anonymous> but was:<null>
```

Answer (score 0):

[SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) has `@Retention(value=SOURCE)` which means that it is not available at runtime:

> [public static final RetentionPolicy SOURCE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE): Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

However, if you would try your code with a different annotation that is available at runtime, `method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)` would still return `null`. That is, because by default the mocked `Method` will return `null` for method calls.

I think your problem is in the configuration of the mock, when I run your code (using an annotation that is available at runtime) I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:466)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:444)
at MockStuff.main(MockStuff.java:54)
```

[This page](http://www.tsolak.com/?p=139) has some explanations about how to mock a final class (such as `Method`).

---

Your code gives the exact same result for me. I was able to get it working using the following code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Method.class)
public class AnnotationClassTest {
  @Test
  public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    final Method mockMethod = PowerMock.createMock(Method.class);
    final Anot mockAnot = EasyMock.createMock(Anot.class);

    EasyMock.expect(mockMethod.getAnnotation(Anot.class)).andReturn(mockAnot);
    PowerMock.replay(mockMethod);

    final Anot methodReturn = mockMethod.getAnnotation(Anot.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(mockAnot, methodReturn);
  }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Anot {}
```

Note that this code is self contained, I defined the `Anot` interface since you didn't give the definition of `Anonymous`.

Comment: when I used my customized annotations which has @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME),I got the same result

Comment: I tried again,but still failed.I typed sources in the page.Could you help me fix this problem?Thank you.

Comment: Yes,your changed code works well.But I need to use mocked Method class in another method just like my code,not directly use the Method class.